# How can I (as a new author) publish a collection of essays?

Tags: publishing

I was never interested in writing until I was around forty years of age.  I have done a fair amount of writing in the past decade or more, mostly emails, personal letters, and messages to various online discussion forums. in the past two years, I have written over a hundred essays, of one to four thousand words each, on a variety of topics and am now interested in publishing a collection of them. I have read [How can I make a collection of essays / arguments more attractive to publishers?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5227/how-can-i-make-a-collection-of-essays-arguments-more-attractive-to-publishers)  and am looking for further advice.

Yes, I realize the odds of success are quite low and any “reasonable” person would tell me to just give up my dream and not even try. Call me a fool or worse, but I must assume that I am brilliant, and that others will be interested in my views on the human condition. How do I get from where I am to having my work published and being read?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Writers.  I've made some changes to your question to focus it more on the problem you're trying to solve and less on the discussion-forum aspect.  I also added a link to the question you referred to; can you [edit] to explain what you're looking for that's not addressed there?  Are you specifically interested in publishing a collection (as a book or e-book), or would blogging or serialized publishing (like in magazines) meet your need?  Please edit to clarify.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider publishing them yourself. It's not hard to do these days. I won't say it's easy (learning the tools will take a bit of time), but it's certainly doable.

At the turn of the year I knew absolutely nothing about producing books. In the four months since then, I have published four short stories as electronic books through various distributors (Kindle, iBooks, Kobo, and Smashwords), and one short story as a paperback (through CreateSpace).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are they doing?